# Spingloops - Deployment of a commit containing file deletions

Tags: git, deployment, ftp, springloops

I have a git repo in Springloops which has automatic FTP deployments for the develop branch. These deployments end up in a Wordpress site.

Let's suppose I commit a file removal in the git repo. Will the deployment actually remove the file from the site's FTP?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question to avoid testing it on my company's account. Turned out the commit had been inadvertently pushed and the answer is

**YES**, a deletion commit will delete the files on the FTP.

Comment: It's also a question that's actually off topic for SO - Server Fault is a better match

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. What I did was Google the question and in the first results I discovered there was already a springloops tag here, so I posted the question.